# Unhandled Rejection (TypeError): history.pushState is not a function

Tags: reactjs, jsx

```
useEffect(() => {
  const generateToken = async() => {
    try {
      const token = await commerce.checkout.generateToken(cart.id, {
        type: 'cart'
      });

      setCheckoutToken(token);
    } catch (error) {
      history.pushState('/');
    }
  }

  generateToken();
  // eslint-disable-next-line react-hooks/exhaustive-deps
}, [cart]);
```

I'm learning React for the first time, and I've encountered an error when using the `history.pushState()` function. How best can i solve this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should be only
`history.push('/');`

```
useEffect(() => {
  const generateToken = async() => {
    try {
      const token = await commerce.checkout.generateToken(cart.id, {
        type: 'cart'
      });

      setCheckoutToken(token);
    } catch (error) {
      history.push('/');
    }
  }

  generateToken();
  // eslint-disable-next-line react-hooks/exhaustive-deps
}, [cart]);
```

Comment: @sammmotaroki if you believe that this is the best solution to your problem, then you should mark this as an "accepted answer".